# Echo one image from mysql with next/prev button

Tags: php, mysql

So I have upload form wich uploads image to foldar and save name to database(mysql). So far I have this:

```
<?php

mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM images LIMIT 1");
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die ("SQL Error: ".mysqli_error($connection));

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<div class=\"picture\">";
echo "<p>";

echo "<img src=\"upload/" . $row['filename']  . "\" alt=\"\" /><br />";
echo $row['caption'] . "<br />";
echo "</p>";
echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

How can I change the code to show me one image at the time.. Like sort of gallery with buttons 'next' and 'prev' to change images?
In DB I store only 'id' and 'filename'.
Thanks

edit:
I made it like this

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
 $id = $_GET['id'];
} else {
$id = 1;
$res=mysqli_query($connection, "select * from images order by id ASC LIMIT  $id, 1");
$prevSQL = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM images WHERE id > '".$id."' LIMIT  1");
$nextSQL = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM images WHERE id < '".$id."' LIMIT 1");

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
if($prevSQL === FALSE) {
    die("SQL Error: " . mysqli_errno($connection));
}
if($nextSQL === FALSE) {
    die("SQL Error: " . mysqli_errno($connection));
}
if(mysqli_num_rows($prevSQL)>1){
$prevRow = mysqli_fetch_array($prevSQL);
$prev = '<a href="show.php?page='.$prevRow['id'].'">Prev</a>';

} else {
$prev = 'Prev';
}
if(mysqli_num_rows($nextSQL)<1){
$nextRow = mysqli_fetch_array($nextSQL);
$next = '<a href="show.php?page='.$nextRow['id'].'">Next</a>';

} else {
$next = 'Next';
}
echo "<img src=\"upload/" . $row['filename']  . "\" alt=\"\" /><br />";
echo $row['caption'] . "<br />";
echo "</p>";
echo "<a href='show.php?page=".$id."'>Next</a>";
echo "<br/>";
echo "<a href='show.php?page=".$id."'>Prev</a>";
echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

Comment: note that limit without order by is pretty much meaningless

Comment: I don't know. I mena they are little now but they will take more with time.

Comment: Just by way of example, take a look at the slideshow on this site.. http://bit.ly/LgFgAG... click on one of the thumbnails to activate the slideshow. This page employs just one hit on the mysql database. Everything else is done in javascript. Generally, except where dealing with huge amounts of data, the fewer round trips to the database, the better.

Comment: @Strawberry is good but is not what I want to achieve.

Comment: My point is really that pagination doesn't have to involve lots of trips to the database

Comment: My goal is something like this [link](http://bit.ly/KnRlDn)

Comment: Sorry, I really can't see the difference.

Comment: I don't want to be like this slideshow on popup.

Comment: So, embed the slideshow - same difference!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make it this way

```
$query = "select * from images order by id asc";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die("Query failed: " . mysqli_errno($connection));

$line = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH);
if (!$line) die('Empty table');
$previd = -1;
$currid = $line[0];
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
do {
    $currid = $line[0];
    if ($currid == $_GET['id']) break;
    $previd = $currid;
    $line = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH);
 } while ($line);
}

if ($line) {
echo "<div id=\"picture\">";
echo "<img style=\"width:100%;margin:0 auto;\" src=\"upload/" . $line['filename']  . "\" alt=\"\" /><br />";
echo $line['caption'] . "<br />";
echo "</p>";


} else echo "No records.\n";

if ($previd > -1) echo '<a href="show.php?id='.$previd.'">Prev | </a>';

$line = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH);
if ($line) echo '<a href="show.php?id='.$line[0].'">Next </a>';
    echo '<br>';
    echo "</div>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [MySQL Limit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) you can do this. Note that it takes two parameters. The first is the starting record so:

```
SELECT * FROM images 
order by ID ASC
LIMIT $page, 1
```

By passing a new $page with every click, you get the next record by ID.

To make sure you have a valid $page at all times:

```
if isset($_GET['page']) {
   $page = $_GET['page'];
} else {
   $page = 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer and what will be $page?

Comment: I assume you can submit a number with your next and prev buttons... `$page = $_GET['page']` or `$page = $_POST['page']` depending on how you implement it.

Comment: I'm updated my question. So far this is working. But now when there is no more images(id's) in DB showing me blank page.. and if I'm on first image(first id) and I hit 'Prev' i get error message. edit// it doesn't work..

Comment: Yes you have to put in checks for those things. Don't show prev if it would be <1, and don't show next if it would be > $result->num_rows.

Comment: I always get `Undefined index: page...` here `$page = $_GET['page'];` I'm sorry for this questions but I still learning php and don't know really why is this error.

Comment: Check my updated answer. Always check to see if a var exists before using it.

Comment: Edited question again.